# Missing Client Identifier in Firebase?

Tags: python, firebase, http, google-cloud-firestore, godot

- I'm using Godot, and also I am using Firebase for store some datas. I
  enabled phone auth, but my problem is why I'm seeing Missing Client
  Identifier error?
- But if I add my number to Whitelist, then I don't see any error.
- This error didn't happen in Email sign up.
- Can someone help me why I 'm seeing this error?

API links:

```
const PHONE_SENDVERIFY := "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?key=%s" % API_KEY
const PHONE_VER := "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPhoneNumber?key=%s" % API_KEY
const PHONE_SIGN := "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPhoneNumber?key=%s" % API_KEY
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! :) How did you get those API links? Can you add reference for those?

Comment: Thanks :), here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth

I saw in Google docs, everything is fine if i add my number to whitelist, but if i remove, then I'm getting missing client identifer error :'(

Comment: I read this reference and there are no such endpoints...

Comment: same issue, any ideas?